# No exact matches in call to instance method 'tableView

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm simply trying to test a tableview cell selection.
I have tried using tableView.selectRow(at:, animated:, scrollPosition:) but the delegate callback is never called.

I am then trying to call the callback directly, which is still a normal method of the class, so it should be available to use, but I'm getting the error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'tableView'"  pointint at the 5th character of the line

```
func testDidSelectIsCalled() {
    sut.tableView(sut.tableView , didSelectRowAt: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) // Error
    presenter.verifyViewDidSelectWasCalled(times: 1)
  }
```

Any idea?
How can I test the code in my delegate?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're aware what to test with UI Test and Unit Test.

If you're doing UI Test, you can test the static texts of your tableView.

But most probably you're doing Unit Test here. In UT, you should test the smallest unit possible, and don't test the `didSelect` of `UITableView` delegate method because IMO it's not your code, and therefore shouldn't be in your concern.

That being said, put your method from the `didSelect` to a new different method, and then proceed to test that new method of yours.

---

Edit: What I mean by don't directly test the `didSelect` as it is not "your code" is that you could really make a better method that the `didSelect` method can call, also it's Apple's piece of code. As you can see in your code, you're calling a "UI" (or `UIKit`)'s piece of code `UITableView` to be specific, and you should not be doing that in your Unit Test.

Comment: Thank you but I don't understand why you say that didSelect is not my code. I handle item selection there. So it must be my code and in xcode's code coverage tool is saying that that function is not tested. So I still have my initial problem and still don't know why  I'm not able to call the delegate method directly doing: sut.tableView(sut.tableView , didSelectRowAt:)

Comment: I edited the answer. Not sure about the other guy's downvote of your question, I think every testing questions should be helpful to others. So perhaps try to add a little bit of your UT code.